# Disallow selecting the empty element of a pop-up menu (a.k.a. drop-down list) such as NativeSelect in Vaadin 8

Tags: drop-down-menu, vaadin, popupmenu, vaadin8

The pop-up menu widget `NativeSelect` in Vaadin 8 displays a list of the possible items along with an empty slot at top, presumably to indicate “no item yet chosen”.

[image]

How can I disable that empty slot, forbid empty selection?

In preparing the layout, I will set one of the items as chosen by default. The user then is required to always choose one. I want to forbid the no-item-selected case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove that empty item from the dropdown, call [`NativeSelect::setEmptySelectionAllowed`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.5.2/com/vaadin/ui/NativeSelect.html#setEmptySelectionAllowed-boolean-):

```
nativeSelect.setEmptySelectionAllowed(false);
```